# component required a bean named 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer$ImportsConfiguration'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting this error while starting spring boot application.

App is running with Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.7.RELEASE

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

A component required a bean named 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer$ImportsConfiguration' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer$ImportsConfiguration' in your configuration.

Also, this class is not public so it is now allowing me to create bean so if anyone faced this error and know resolution I would be appreciate your effort.

Comment: Not sure why would test class fail while running your app but try adding spring test jar. _org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test_. How are you running your app?

Comment: I have this dependency added in the project and running spring boot app from eclipse testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.6.RELEASE")